# Azure DevOps Start Chat is not responding to click

Tags: azure-devops, chat

On project overview, member section displaying users icon and when I click someone I get a popup with two option email and start chat.

I click the start chat but nothing happens. Is there a configuration what I need to do?

Is it because I am using the free trial Azure DevOps
please someone help as I am trailing for our company.

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

MS use SIP protocol to initiate chat in the client, which is handled by apps such as Skype for Business and Microsoft Teams. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Please check whether you have installed Skype for Business or Microsoft Teams on your client machine, and make sure you have enabled Popups for your project overview page in the browser settings.

In addition, try with other browsers to see whether you have the window pop up.

Comment: Getting the "Microsoft 365 Business Basic" subscription, made it work for me.   Without it nothing would happen as stated in the question.   The Teams (community edition without channels)  would not be proposed as an app even if I had it on my desktop.